# Why does dataRow always contains the first row

Tags: c#, foreach, datatable

In my project I have to monitor the status of a decentralized periphery. For this I created a class that mirrors a single data point with name, address etc. Now I want to insert all my single objects of the class DataPoint into a SortedList . The DataPoint objects should be initialized via a DataTable. My problem is that in my Foreach loop I always have the first two of the DataTable. So that I create a SortedList with 39 times the same entry in this example. If the classes DataPoint and DpPeriphyData Class contain the SortedList, the program runs without problems.

```
private void Cmd_Fbd_Data_List_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImportExportExcelToDataGridClass excel = new ImportExportExcelToDataGridClass();
    DataTable dataPointList = excel.ImportExceltoDataGrid(); 
    Dgv_Data_List.DataSource = dataPointList; 
    Dgv_Data_List.ReadOnly = true; 
    DpPeripheryData InputData = new DpPeripheryData(); 

    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataPointList.Rows) 
    {
        DataPoint dataPoint = new DataPoint(dataRow); // making a new objekt 
        InputData.AddDataPoint(dataPoint); // add this class to the Sorted List 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your local variable InputData doesn't seem to be kept around once your method is finished. It isn't assigned to any instance outside of your method so it will be garbage collected once your event handler has finished. Unless `AddDataPoint` does magic you didn't share here.

Comment: Thanks! Is it better to make the SortedList<int,Class> classList static or to make the InputData to a field of the Main Form?

Comment: Both will work I guess, assuming that gets assigned to a datagridview